# Есть textView с таким же отображением ссылок и кода?

Tags: android

Вопрос [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой же TextView или есть ли готовые библиотеки??(имею ввиду чтобы загружать код с страницы, а он при отображение имел такой или похожий вид)

Фото из приложения TechMedia

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения "кода со страницы", я так полагаю, нам надо загрузить эту страницу и отобразить ее. А для этого есть элемент WebView. Но будь осторожен, в этот момент твое приложение превратится из нативного в веб-посредственность и потеряет всяческий смысл существования, ведь его можно будет получить просто открыв страничку!

А чтобы узнать, как сделана та или иная фича в чужом приложении, есть отличные утилиты вроде АПКТула, которая позволит разобрать уже скомпилированное приложение и посмотреть, как же оно устроено внутри.

Читай чужой код, повторяй сам, расширяй грани познания и только так ты станешь экспертом!

Comment: Хотите сказать, что нету "интересных" библиотек и примеров с textView??

Comment: Вам нравится побираться на помойках в поисках каких-то интересных объедков, оставшихся с барского стола, когда можно надеть белоснежный колпак и фартук и приготовить все это самому, причем именно так, как вам этого хочется?

Comment: Мне не хочется изобретать велосипед. Не знаю зачем пересоздавать, что и так хорошо работает

Comment: Тогда используйте это, раз оно доступно! Я бы вот тоже не хотел изобретать велосипед каждый день, готовя салаты или супы на кухне, к тому же с нуля, но если покупать все готовое -  получается слишком дорого, а если заводить жену - остается мало времени. Так что мне проще изобретать велосипеды каждый день.

Comment: А не подскажите ещё как называется в тулбаре сверху слева 3 линии(вк например)и как переходя на фрагмент или в другой активити заменить их стрелкой)))??